# C# compiler is picking the wrong assembly for a type

Tags: c#, types, reference, .net-assembly

We have recently split some shared code from one assembly into two assemblies both named differently from the original. When updating an application I have removed all references to the old assembly and added references to the two new assemblies. When compiling the code it tells me I must add a reference to the old assembly for some of the types even though those types are defined in one of the new assemblies.

> The type 'ICustomerDetails' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'OldAssembly,
>   Version=xxxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx'.

Example Code

```
using newAssemblyOne; -resharper says it not needed
using newAssemblyTwo;

....

var obj = customer.Details;
```

`customer` is an interface defined in `newAssemblyTwo` which the compiler is happy with.
Details is an interface of type `ICustomerDetails` defined in `newAssemblyOne` which the compiler is complaining about.

`customerDetails` works fine when ran from `newAssemblyTwo`.
the application and both assemblies all have the same target framework.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try cleaning up the solution. delete all Bin directories and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Delete `obj`folder too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, still errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had been provided the wrong version of one of the assemblies